# How can I access a variable from another method in Java?

Tags: java, variables, global-variables, local-variables

So, I am trying to access my variable from timer task, however I can't seem to make it work. I read about global variables but wasn't quite sure on how to use it. I am new to Java so any suggestion would be extremely helpful, thank you!

```
public boolean verifyAnswer(String userAnswer) {
    

    
    String correctAnswer = this.questions.get(currentQuestionIndex).correctAnswerText;
    if(userAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
        timer.pauseTimer();
        Timer t = new Timer();
        
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            //This is the variable I want to use

            int score = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(++score);
                if (score == 30) {
                    t.cancel();
                }
            };
        };
        
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);
        TimerPanel timer2 = new TimerPanel();
        
        long total = 0;

        //Here is where I try to use it
        long equation = TimerTask.score / 30000;
```

Answer (score 1):

a global variable might indeed help. It is just a variable declared **outside** the methods but **inside** the class. Then it is visible in the entire class - and also from outside if you make it `public`.

of you are in a multithreading environment, please access it in a synchronized way, like so

```
public class Test {

    public volatile int global_variable = 42;

    public synchronized int getGlobal_variable() {
        return global_variable;
    }

    public synchronized void setGlobal_variable(int global_variable) {
        this.global_variable = global_variable;
    }

    public void update() {
        setGlobal_variable(getGlobal_variable() + 150);

    }

    public Test() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(getGlobal_variable());
                update();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

note that I have added the `volatile` just to be on the safe side.
it depends upon your application whether you really need that.

if you are not concerned with multithreading, just move the declaration of `score` **outside** your method and you will be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround would be to use a single-element array or holder object to store the score as anonymous inner classes cannot modify the value of outer variables.

```
int[] score = {0};
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(++score[0]);
        if (score[0] == 30) {
            t.cancel();
        }
    };
};
//...
long equation = score[0] / 30000;
```